# How to set @PartFilename of Entity field in @POST RESTEasy client method in runtime?

Tags: java, jax-rs, multipartform-data, resteasy

I am trying to write Resteasy Client Class to make simple POST multipart/form-data request to upload file. So POST request must contain `Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files"; filename="myfile.txt"` parameters. 
I am able to set this statically with @PartFilename annotation for field in entity (value) class. like this

```
public class UploadStreamMultipartBody {

    @FormParam("files")
    @PartFilename(value = "myfile.txt")
    @PartType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
    public InputStream file;

}
```

But I cannot realize how to make it dynamically so I can provide file name in RUNTIME  
Cause annotation value is read once in compile time.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Stuck on the same thing! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use `MultipartFormDataOutput` instead.

Interface example:

```java
    @POST
    @Path("/document-store")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    void uploadDocument(@MultipartForm MultipartFormDataOutput data);
```

Usage:

```
var form = new MultipartFormDataOutput();
form.addFormData(/*key=*/"file", inputStream, new MediaType("application", "pdf"), fileName);
documentStoreClient.uploadDocument(form);
```